# Hibernate dependencies in maven not availible in the bean

Tags: hibernate, jsf, maven

Im trying to set up a jsf,hibernate project running in a jboss container. My pom file should pull in my dependencies and let me access my hibernate annotations in my bean class.
However the hibernate jar files are pulled into my target folder and the annotations that come from these jars are not available to me in my class folder, even when I try to import org.hibernate. 
Is there a step where Im supposed to add these jars manually after I pull them in with maven, Id imagine this should be done automatically?

Below is my pom file.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>net.bluedash</groupId>
<artifactId>jsfdemo</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>jsfdemo Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>jvnet-nexus-releases</id>
        <name>jvnet-nexus-releases</name>
        <url>https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/releases/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>jboss-public-repository-group</id>
        <name>JBoss Public Repository Group</name>
        <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>jboss-public-repository-group</id>
        <name>JBoss Public Repository Group</name>
        <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- MySQL database driver -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.9</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Hibernate framework -->
<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
<version>4.1.9.Final</version>
```

```
<!-- Hibernate library dependecy start -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>cglib</groupId>
    <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
<!-- Hibernate library dependecy end -->

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
    <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>


<build>
    <!-- This lets maven know where the hibernate cfg file is -->
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <directory>resources.hibernate</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>deploy</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

    <finalName>jsfdemo</finalName>
</build>
```

Comment: In eclipse I used the same pom file and instead of creating a project from the command line I used maven plugin to create a new maven project.I then copied in this pom changed the names to reflect my new project and right clicked on my project->Maven->update project and this created the correct folder structure I was looking for and downloaded all my dependencies. Is there a maven commanline command for this procedure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside eclipse, once I downloaded the maven extensions, I was able to right click on my project->select Maven->update project. 
This cause my project to build itself and produced the project as it should be.

Answer (score 0):

Please add:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>                      
</dependency>
```

Where:
 
hibernate.version = 3.4.0.GA for JPA1
4.1.x.final for JPA2

hibernate-entitymanager will download hibernate-annotations and hibernate-jpa-2.0-api.